# Error with JSTL when using Spring Boot Jetty embedded

Tags: java, spring, jstl, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to use Spring Boot Starter Web for my project. Somehow it can't run with embedded Tomcat, so I have to change to use embedded Jetty. This is a part of my POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I go into a page, which use JSTL taglib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` it return this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/user.login.jsp(3,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:172)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:431)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:502)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:582)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1657)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:185)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<display-name>Starfall Website</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>starfall-webui</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value />
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>starfall-webui</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/starfall-webui-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.chamgroup.web.controller.CustomContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/web.404</location>
</error-page>
```

Update dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.chamgroup.starfall:starfall-webui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.3.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.M0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211821:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.2.v20130121:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.5:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.11.1.1:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet-wildcard:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-mustache:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-freemarker:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-freemarker:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-velocity:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-velocity:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-el:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-mvel:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-ognl:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jboss:javassist:jar:3.7.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-compat:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:4.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.model:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.common:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.htmlparser:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.0-rc3:compile
[INFO] +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.vietspiderdb:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sleepycat:je:jar:6.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.embededb:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:jar:v3-rev107-1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtubeAnalytics:jar:v1-rev24-1.17.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.18.0-rc:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.nlp:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-tools:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-maxent:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.jwordnet:jwnl:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:20040117.000000:compile
[INFO] +- org.vietspider:org.vietspider.io:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oracle:ojdbc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.1.107:compile
[INFO] |  +- jtds:jtds:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:53.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.rome:rome:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.facebook4j:facebook4j-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.9:compile
```

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree` and include the output in your question

Comment: ok @JoakimErdfelt, i just have updated it in above

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 JSTL Jars, and a bad version you declared, and another one on your jetty-jsp artifacts.

1. Set `jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile` to `<scope>provided</scope>` to get around the fact that `jetty-jsp` has its own jstl jar
2. Set `jetty-jsp` to same version of Jetty as the rest of your dependencies (namely `<version>9.2.13.v20150730</version>`)

When you use embedded-jetty with JSPs, there's a lot of setup you need to go through to ensure that the JSP environment is sane.

See the example project for all these requirements at ...

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/

> **Unrelated Note**: You are using *solr*, be sure you only use it in client mode to talk to a remote solr server, as when you upgrade to solr 5+ it can no longer work integrated in a server like that.